# Weird cutouts in stroke Illustrator CC 2015

Tags: adobe-illustrator, creative-cloud, cc-2015

[image: Strange cutout at top left corner]

For some reason, no matter what size I set the stroke to, there is always a strange cutout or an add on in a corner where two strokes meet. I've even tried changing the corner type and the limit. Still nothing.

Does anyone know what could be causing this? I would appreciate any insight into the problem.

Comment: Is the path a **closed** path?

Comment: It is. I actually figures it out. I had the object way too small, so I'm getting rid of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in the latest Illustrator CC — got to `View > Preview on CPU` and it should render properly.

You'll have to do this for every file you open — I don't think there's a way to set a default, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you so much! That actually worked! I appreciate it. I t was actually really tiny and I don't think that was helping, but even with it being really tiny like that, it worked.

Now I know for future reference.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. You can disable the GPU preview in the App by unchecking "GPU Performance" in the Preferences. This would prevent the need to change it for every file.